# Can I have extra columns in a specific html row? Is there a standard approach for modification of html rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some data to display in a web page. So I display them in an `html` table.
Now I want to be able to modify any row of of the table (which represents a record of the data in the database).
I am not sure if there is a more "standard" approach for this but what I thought of is to add 2 checkboxes in 2 extra columns, 1 checkbox to modify the row and another to delete the row.
Now I am not sure what is the best way to actually save the modification/deletion.
Should I add 2 buttons on modify (`SAVE` and `CANCEL`)? In this case should I have created 2 extra columns for the table in the first place or can I have 2 extra columns in the specific row?
Is there a better approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: `what is the best way to actually save`, what do you mean "save"? Download a new `.html`?

Comment: So only certain rows can be modified/deleted?  What is the criteria?

Comment: @PaulS.:Save the modifications of the user on the row

Comment: @ExplosionPills:The user goes on a row and modifies it. Is this more clear?

Comment: @ExplosionPills:I mean that the user can choose any row.When the page is first fetched the table is not modifiable.A row becomes modifiable once I click modify checkbox for this row.

Comment: So when you click the check box the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons appear?

Comment: @ExplosionPills:Well that is what I thought if it is possible.If there is another way I am interested

Comment: @Cratylus what other way would there be?  Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: @ExplosionPills:I am not sure how to implement this. I assume that the specific row should have 2 more columns than the other rows to contain the `save` `cancel` buttons? And I am also asking if there are other better ways

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31047/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-cratylus)