# Could a form be enclosed in a cell of an html table?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am using a table to allow a user to see/modify/delete data (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875934/can-i-have-extra-columns-in-a-specific-html-row-is-there-a-standard-approach-fo)).
I am interested in knowing what are elements that should **NOT** be enclosed in a cell of an HTML table?
So far I have enclosed `select` and `text` boxes.
I was wondering could I enclose a form? Are there elements I should not enclose?

Comment: Have you checked [the standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/)? The HTML5 specs are actually quite clear and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. `<form>` element is declared in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element), [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_Flow) and [HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/strict.dtd) as the one of `Flow content` category. While it cannot be a *direct* child of `table`, `tbody` or `tr` elements, it can be the [content of `<td>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#the-td-element). That's why this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>T</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td><form action="http://example.com/"></form></td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

... successfully passes both HTML5, XHTML and HTML4.01 validation [here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) (you just have to augment the DOCTYPE as relevant).

Comment: Why not? Is it discouraged by a standard?

Comment: It's also valid in HTML4.01 afaik

Comment: That other answer you linked to doesn't quite apply. `<table><tr><form>...` is invalid due to the [content restrictions on `<tr>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/tr.html#tr-content-model), `<table><tr><td><form>...` is fine because (as you note) [`<td>`s can contain flow content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/td.html#td-content-model) and that includes `<form>`. But +1 for getting it right and correcting your original error.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to. As far as I'm aware there's no limitation on what can be inside a table cell.

Comment: But this form would not send elements of the outer parts of the table, right?

Comment: Right... Forms can only send elements that are inside them, except in HTML5 where you can speciy that an element belongs to another form.

Comment: Yes.I was wondering how to use the form in a column to send data from the row of the table

Comment: There are limitations, but they're the same one as for a div or body: no title element, meta, head, body or html ^^

Comment: The restrictions on what can go inside a `<td>` is [quite clearly spelled out in the standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/td.html#td-content-model).